# Python передача аргумента метода в названии переменной

Tags: python, методы

Можно ли как то изменить название переменной с помощью аргумента метода?

```
def ape(x):
    const.ape_(x).append('1')
    return ape_(x)
```

Как правильно это написать?

Comment: Конечно, то что вы хотите можно сделать, но лучше тупо список сделать, и обращаться к его элементам по индексу.

Comment: Да, тоже думал так сделать. Так, в общем-то, и со списком файлов делал. Но правильнее, все же, через аргумент будет в данном случае. Могли бы Вы подсказать как?

Comment: Правильнее через список, остальное от лукавого.

Comment: А ты мог бы показать, как?

Comment: Просто `ape = []`, потом значение добавляем в список, например так: `ape.append(x)`. Ну а дальше обращаемся к значениям по индексу через `ape[i]`.